# How would i add custom spell checking to quilljs?

Tags: javascript, spell-checking, quill, rich-text-editor

I'm building a website where I need to control the dictionary of the spell checking in a Quill editor. I have googled a lot and can not find any simple way to do this.

Ideally, I would like to do something like a spell checking browser extension would (e.g. LanguageTool or Grammarly) and just overlay the existing editor. I can however not find any good source code to reference or any tutorials on how to add highlighting to quill without disturbing the editing experience. (I tried looking into using

I have also researched quill modules for spell checking, but could not find any. I also started looking into the highlight.js module, but it does not seem to be relevant in this case.